# Server side datatable with multi column search

Tags: php, search, datatable

I am using data table for showing records and i have more then 50 thousand records.

before using server side script in database it's take too much time but multi search was working, when i change basic listing to server side listing it's coming fast but multi search is not working.

[data listing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWNhb.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You must implement a function for searching your database rows on the server-side. Read the [DataTables documentation](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) for more.

Answer (score -1):

Read the manual:[Datatables manual](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

And study examples:[Examples](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)